# Pytest+aioresponses customclient issue

Tags: pytest, aiohttp

Why it's not possible to mock request with `aioresponses` if I use `ClientSession` in such way

```
class BaseClient:
    def __init__(self, token: str, org_id: str):
        self._url = "https://api.tracker.yandex.net"
        self._version = "v2"
        self._params = RequestParams()
        self._headers = {
            "Authorization": f"OAuth {token}",
            "X-Org-ID": org_id,
        }
        self._session = ClientSession(
            base_url=self._url, headers=self._headers, raise_for_status=True
        )

    async def __aenter__(self) -> "BaseClient":
        return self

    async def __aexit__(
        self,
        exc_type: typing.Optional[typing.Type[BaseException]],
        exc_val: typing.Optional[BaseException],
        exc_tb: typing.Optional[TracebackType],
    ) -> None:
        await self._session.close()

    async def close(self):
        await self._session.close()

    async def get(
        self,
        url: str,
        params: typing.Dict[str, typing.Any] | None = None,
    ):
        default_params = self._params.dict(by_alias=True)
        if params:
            default_params.update(params)
        return await self._session.get(
            f"{self._version}/{url}",
            params=default_params,
        )
```

Fixtures

```
@pytest_asyncio.fixture()
async def get_client():
    async with BaseClient(
        os.environ["YANDEX_TOKEN"], os.environ["TRACKER_ORG_ID"]
    ) as client:
        yield client


@pytest.fixture
def mocker():
    with aioresponses(passthrough=["https://api.tracker.yandex.net/"]) as m:
        yield m


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def get_primary_queue_id():
    return "QUEUEONE
```

"

Mock

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_issue_parameters(mocker, get_client, get_primary_issue_id):
    resp = """{
        "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/issues/TREK-9844",
        "id": "593cd211ef7e8a332414f2a7",
        "key": "TREK-9844",
        "version": 7,
        "lastCommentUpdatedAt": "2017-07-18T13:33:44.291+0000",
        "summary": "subtask",
        "parent": {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/issues/JUNE-2",
            "id": "593cd0acef7e8a332414f28e",
            "key": "JUNE-2",
            "display": "Task"
            },
        "aliases": [
                "JUNE-3"
            ],

        "updatedBy": {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/users/1120000000016876",
            "id": "<id employee>",
            "display": "<emloyee display name>"
            },
        "description": "<#<html><head></head><body><div>test</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div> </body></html>#>",
        "sprint": [
                {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/sprints/5317",
            "id": "5317",
            "display": "sprin1"
                }
            ],
        "type": {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/issuetypes/2",
            "id": "2",
            "key": "task",
            "display": "Task"
            },
        "priority": {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/priorities/2",
            "id": "2",
            "key": "normal",
            "display": "Normal"
            },

        "createdAt": "2017-06-11T05:16:01.339+0000",
        "followers": [
            {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/users/1120000000016876",
            "id": "<id>",
            "display": "<name>"
            }
            ],
        "createdBy": {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/users/1120000000049224",
            "id": "<id>",
            "display": "<name>"
            },
        "votes": 0,
        "assignee": {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/users/1120000000049224",
            "id": "<id>",
            "display": "<name>"
            },
        "queue": {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/queues/TREK",
            "id": "111",
            "key": "TREK",
            "display": "Startrek"
            },
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-18T13:33:44.291+0000",
        "status": {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/statuses/1",
            "id": "1",
            "key": "open",
            "display": "Open"
            },
        "previousStatus": {
            "self": "https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/statuses/2",
            "id": "2",
            "key": "resolved",
            "display": "Resolved"
            },
        "favorite": false
    }
    """
    mocker.get(
        f"https://api.tracker.yandex.net/v2/issues/{get_primary_issue_id}",
        headers={
            "Authorization": f"OAuth {os.environ['YANDEX_TOKEN']}",
            "X-Org-ID": os.environ["TRACKER_ORG_ID"],
        },
        status=200,
        payload=resp,
    )
    r = await issues.query.params(get_client, get_primary_issue_id)
    assert isinstance(r, issues.models.IssueParametersResponse)
```

What I see in exception is just a part of URL, like `base_url` param is not used

```
./tests/test_issues.py::test_get_issue_parameters Failed: [undefined]aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectionError: Connection refused: GET v2/issues/QUEUEONE-1?page=1&perPage=50

self = <aioresponses.core.aioresponses object at 0x7f96b854b550>
orig_self = <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f96b8630810>
method = 'GET', url = URL('v2/issues/QUEUEONE-1?page=1&perPage=50'), args = ()
kwargs = {'allow_redirects': True, 'params': {'page': 1, 'perPage': 50}}
url_origin = 'v2/issues/QUEUEONE-1'
url_str = 'v2/issues/QUEUEONE-1?page=1&perPage=50'
prefix = 'https://api.tracker.yandex.net/'
key = ('GET', URL('v2/issues/QUEUEONE-1?page=1&perPage=50'))
request_call = RequestCall(args=(), kwargs={'params': {'perPage': 50, 'page': 1}, 'allow_redirects': True})
response = None
```